# Convert Crystalreport's Provider from 'SQLNCLI' to 'SQLOLEDB' by code (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Is it possible to convert crystalreport's Provider from 'SQLNCLI' to 'SQLOLEDB' by code "c#"

I have tried with following code but did not work.

```
TableLogOnInfo logoninfo;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tbcurrent in rptH.Database.Tables)
            {
                logoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
                logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = connectionInfo.DatabaseName;
                logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = connectionInfo.ServerName;
                logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = connectionInfo.UserID;
                logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = connectionInfo.Password;
                tbcurrent.ApplyLogOnInfo(logoninfo);
            }
            rptH.SetDatabaseLogon(connectionInfo.UserID, connectionInfo.Password, connectionInfo.ServerName, connectionInfo.DatabaseName, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < rptH.Subreports.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tbcurrent in rptH.Subreports[i].Database.Tables)
                {
                    logoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
                    logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = connectionInfo.DatabaseName;
                    logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = connectionInfo.ServerName;
                    logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = connectionInfo.UserID;
                    logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = connectionInfo.Password;
                    tbcurrent.ApplyLogOnInfo(logoninfo);
                }
                rptH.Subreports[i].SetDatabaseLogon(connectionInfo.UserID, connectionInfo.Password, connectionInfo.ServerName, connectionInfo.DatabaseName, true);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this can be done as the connection type seems to be stored in the `.rpt` file.
But you can try use native .Net API to retrieve database selection into a `System.Data.DataSet` / `System.Data.DataTable` instance and call `Table.SetDataSource()` to set as the table data source, so you do not need to care about `TableLogOnInfo` object, but please ensure the scheme matches that of the report.

Below sample codes are from Crystal Reports .NET API Guide:

```
private void SetDataSource
   (string conn, string query, DataSet dataSet)
{
   OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(conn);
   OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
   oleAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, oleConn);

   oleAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customer");

   reportDocument.Database.Tables["Customer"].SetDataSource (dataSet);
}
```

Besides, `ReportDocument` also has `SetDataSource()` method, so you can set the data source for the whole report.